# If white light is passed through a spectrometer can we observe all 7 colors from it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

> If white light (sunlight) is passed through a spectrometer can we observe all 7 colors from it?

I know that spectrometer is having a prism in it. And the prism has the capability to refract white to rainbow colors. But I have a dought if you observe any light ray from the equipment, you cannot see its actual color. Please Help me. I haven't used a spectrometer on my own.

Comment: Did you do any research on how colours are observed by human vision ?

Comment: Yes, I know that colors are observed when it is reflected from an object. What if we remove green color component from the white light and observe it from a spectrometer? according to answers given I can conclude that we can observe whole spectrum without green. Am I right?

Comment: that is correct but you should also know about the cone cells that can observe green, red and blue. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell

Comment: The answer to your title question is yes. Period. Newton did this in 1665 and others did it long before him, though without fully understanding what they were seeing.

Comment: Thanks @Ed V ,,, also V.F. gave a descriptive answer to it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you looked directly at the refracted white light coming out of a prism, you would not necessarily see all seven colors of rainbow.

If the source of (close to) white light is the sun or a white light bulb, the spectrum of the light is continuous and includes all seven colors of rainbow and everything in between.

However, white light, or, more precisely, what we perceive as white color, could also be produced by a certain mixture of red, green and blue sources or other, properly weighted, combinations of colors, in which case its spectrum will show just those source colors and not necessarily all colors of rainbow.

Answer (score 0):

A spectrometer is a measuring apparatus, so light goes to a detector, you can't see it.

I guess you're rather looking for a **Monochromator**. Spectrometers usually use a monocrhomator.

However, the prism has been long time superceeded by other separating techniques, such as difraction gratings, which work much better if used correctly.

Comment: Spectrometers can come as devices with scopes to see the diffraction patterns with your own eyes

Answer (score 0):

Yes in theory, although in practice the number of actual distinct colours you see is dependent on imagination.

The reason we say there are 7 colours is more to do with Newton being interested in Biblical mysticism than any optical or physiological effect

Answer (score -2):

No, you could observe red, green and blue only. A TV monitor makes colors by mixing or adding them. If you look close at the TV screen with a Magnifying glass you’ll see three colors red green and blue that when added in certain proportions make all the colors including white.